# Null pointer exception showing in action bar sherlock library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to implement the search view widget of Sherlock action bar. My problem is `OnOptionItemSelected` of search view item. I am getting a null pointer exception in library activity.

The menu xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
/>
```

Code snippet for option menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tvguide_menu, menu);
    MenuItem mSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search for countriesâ€¦");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearch.setActionView(searchView);
    mSearch.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM |
            MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
}
```

I am getting a forced close on clicking over search android. I have shared my log below

```
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.toString(MenuItemImpl.java:490)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:201)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:953)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:491)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:110)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4438)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-17 15:10:08.508: E/AndroidRuntime(23283):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: stacktrace from logcat please?

Comment: I have shared pls have a look.

Comment: logcat error you added is not visible pls check it

Comment: I think it should be searchView = (SearchView) mSearch.getActionView(), not new SearchView()

Comment: @DoctororDrive i changed the code but still getting same log cat android

Comment: Yes, it will not solve the OP problem, that's just another error. Also it is more easier to write android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" in menu.xml. What the error is I think that your SearchView is not created for some reason. Did you use Theme.Sherlock for this activity? Did you include ActionBarSherlock as a library project of your project?

Comment: I found the error o didnt specify title for menu...now works fine... thank u all

Comment: I also got it after upgrading to 4.3.0...

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that your `Menu` item does not specify an title, and in the line :

```
@Override
public final boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, android.view.MenuItem item) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "[onMenuItemSelected] featureId: " 
           + featureId + ", item: " + item);
    ...
}
```

`item` will inkove the `toString()` method which :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return mTitle.toString();
}
```

will throw a `NullPointerException`. A easy workaround for this, until it will be fixed is to use :

```
android:title=""
```

for your `MenuItem`.

Also, this will not happen on a release of your application.

Answer (score 6):

It is a bug in version 4.3.0 of ActionBarSherlock, I fixed it in this way (you need to comment the line 201 of actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragmentActivity.java  :

```
--- a/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragmentActivity.java
+++ b/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragmentActivity.java
@@ -198,7 +198,7 @@ public class SherlockFragmentActivity extends Watson implements OnActionModeStar

     @Override
     public final boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, android.view.MenuItem item) {
-        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "[onMenuItemSelected] featureId: " + featureId + ", item: " + item);
+       // if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "[onMenuItemSelected] featureId: " + featureId + ", item: " + item);

         if (featureId == Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL && !mIgnoreNativeSelected) {
             mIgnoreNativeSelected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone faces this problem and wants to create the menu item with no title, this nullpointerexception can be solved by simply modifying the `toString()` method in `com/android/internal/view/menu/MenuItemImpl` class from actionbarsherlock source code to do a null string check before return:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return (mTitle != null)? mTitle.toString(): "";
}
```